# Repeat insert statement without GO <x>

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a "nicer" way to achieve the same results as this SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO [MyDB]..[MyTable] VALUES
(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
GO 300
```

Which is to insert 300 default all NULL (except PK Id col) new lines into an empty table?
It seems to take a while!

Also, the value 300 could be completely variable e.g. something like

```
GO select max(Id) from [SERVER_X].[MyDb].[dbo].[Logs]
```

but that obviously doesn't work:

```
 A fatal scripting error occurred.
 Incorrect syntax was encountered while parsing GO.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with n as (
      select 1 as n, max(Id) as max_id 
      from [SERVER_X].[MyDb].[dbo].[Logs]
      union all
      select n + 1, max_id
      from n
      where n < max_id
     )
insert into t
    select null, null, null, null
    from n
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Inserting rows where all values are `NULL` seems to be not very useful.  But, [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a12b7e9fbfb6446bb29d07b0a42391b2) is a db<>fiddle with an `identity` `id` column.

Comment: It's a quick fix in a migration script to get round the fact someone deleted a bunch of identity rows from the old database. I need to keep the identity / key numbers the same so I'm inserting a bunch of empty rows then doing a simple join on ones that still exist. Wasn't sure how else to go about it.

Comment: @jamheadart. . . If that case then you can use this statement first `select 1 as n, max(Id) as max_id from [SERVER_X].[MyDb].[dbo].[Logs]` instead of hardcore values to `300`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff. . . I have changed the `select` statement with dynamic max value. Hope, If you don't mind with this.

Comment: @YogeshSharma . . . No problem.  Thank you.